# Issues with MatAutocomplete : Dropdown is coming at the bottom

Tags: css, angular, frontend

I am new to Angular. And using MatAutocomplete from angular material on one of my pages. Whats happening is when i click on the dropdown, the dropdown options are coming at the bottom of the page instead of coming next to the input field. I feel some css change is needed. Here is the code.:

```
 <div class="uitk-l-grid__row">
            <div class="uitk-l-grid__col--6">
                <div class="demo-l-grid-col-content">
                    <label uitkLabel> Health Insurance Carrier: </label>
                    <uitk-form-field-hint> Please select from the common list of carriers. If the carrier is not listed, please type below. </uitk-form-field-hint>

                    <input type="text"
                           placeholder="Pick one"
                           aria-label="Number"
                           matInput
                           [matAutocomplete]="auto">
                    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of options" [value]="item">
                            {{item}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-autocomplete>
                </div>
            </div>
```

```
export class SubmitReferralAndRequest1Component implements OnInit {
    input: UITKInputDirective;
    options = ['Option1','Option2','Option3']}
```

I tried changing the css a bit but no luck. I have not added any css code for the matautocomplete.
Just added matautocomplete in my app.modulte.ts
import {MatAutocomplete, MatAutocompleteModule} from "@angular/material/autocomplete";